# Unable to view images in mvc3 application hosted in iis 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web, web-hosting

I have hosted my asp .net mvc3 application in iis server 7. I had deployed my application under a virtual directory  and url to my application is like www.abc.com/virtualdirname . Application works fine and Im able to navigate through pages. However , Im unable to view any images used in my application.  I have stored my images in a folder public/images .
cshtml code for one of the image is as follows
**img id="start" src="../../Public/images/start_button_start.png"**

Im getting error message in place of images and path of image is www.abc.com/public/images instead of www.abc.com/virtualdirname/public/images .

In the app settings of my config file, I had defined virtual dir.
**add key="virtualdir" value="/virtualdirname " /**

Can anyone tell me why this problem happens and how can I get out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use url helpers:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/start_button_start.png")" alt=""/>
```

Url helpers will take virtual directory into account.